# How to create Outlook rule from Powershell with st_only_when_oof

Tags: powershell, outlook, office-interop, rules

I try to create a new rule in powershell with Microsoft.office.interop.outlook that execute only when Out Of Office is enable for the user.

I should set the Bit st_only_when_oof but i don"t know how

Actual script :

```
Add-Type -Assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject "Outlook.Application"
$Namespace = $Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$Rules = $Namespace.DefaultStore.GetRules()

$Rule = $Rules.create("Gestion Absence",[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlRuleType]::olRuleReceive)


$Condition = $Rule.Conditions.SenderAddress
$Condition.Enabled = $true
$Condition.Address = @("xxx@xxx.com")

$Action = $Rule.Actions.Delete
$Action.Enabled = $true


$Rules.Save()
```

All is fine except the rule trigger always and i need it only when Out of office.

Redemption DLL is not an option because i have issues with this DLL with outlook 365

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in Outlook Object Model. You can use `ST_ONLY_WHEN_OOF` in Extended MAPI, but it is only available in C++ or Delphi. If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (any language - I am its author) is an option, it exposes the [RDORule](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdorule.htm).`OnlyWhenOOF` property.